# How to dynamically change css values (like color in whole app) etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have one question...

If you want conditional styling: you must use `ng-class` or `ng-style` construction.

But...

For example: I'm an admin, and I want to change color of my application with custom color from `colorpicker`. How can I change some code in css?

For example I have this line in `style.css`:

```
body{
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

(also all tags like a, h1 etc implement some color)

and in controller I change this `#ffffff` to `#000000`.

What is the best way to change this color in css, without using `ng-class` or `ng-style` on each tag in each controller?

Answer (score 5):

The best way is generate a file like color.css with all css rules with `color`, `background-color`, `border-color` etc. overridden. But angularjs will not be enough.

**color-default.css**

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}
```

**color.css**

```
body {
    background: #f00;
}
```

---

**Full JS way**
Add class on every element you want to override.
Create class for every properties like so:

```
.skin-color { color: {{color}}; }
.skin-background-color { background-color: {{color}}; }
.skin-border-color { border-color: {{color}}; }
etc..
```

Apply class on your html where you want:

```
<h1 class="skin-color">My title</h1>
<p>Hello I'm online!</p>
<p class="skin-background-color">No difference!</p>
<p><a href="#">I'm link</a></p>
```

You can save the color variable in localStorage for example.
**Démo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPrabY**

Answer (score 4):

You could write the CSS rule in JavaScript and add it to a stylesheet dynamically. A couple of good articles on how to do that are [here](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) and [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript).

```
var myColor = '#FF00FF';
var stylesheet = /* get stylesheet element */;
stylesheet.insertRule('.dynamic-color { background-color:"' + myColor +'";}',0);
```

Of course, in a pure Angular way, you would create a directive that wraps the DOM/stylesheet interaction.

Comment: hm, how it is better to get stylesheet in angular? maybe you have some code?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 There is some code for that at each of the two links. The simplest method would be to add an ID to your stylesheet and retrieve it using document.getElementById.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think about is, for example, clicking on myBox changes its background-color.

html:

```
<div class="myBox" ng-click="changeBackgroundColor()"></div>
```

js:

```
$scope.changeBackgroundColor = function(){
  angular.element('.myBox').css('background-color', '#000');
}
```

css:

```
.myBox{background-color: #fff;}
```

Hope I've been helpfull.

Answer (score -7):

Another alternative is SASS or LESS and deal with colors using variable...