# Change border color Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello im very new to HTML and Javascript.Im trying to create prompt where user able to input color they want the boarder to change its border color. can anyone help me with this problem please point out what i need and where.Thank you all who can and cant help .
 Bellow is code i have so far

```
<script>
    var getColor = prompt("Choose your color ", "Enter the  color ");
    var color;
    var el = document.getElementById("color");
   el.innerHTML = "Whatever paragraph message.";
    if (getColor == "Yellow" || getColor == "yellow" || getColor == "YELLOW") {
        color = "#FFFF66";
        el.style.borderColor = color;
    }
    else if (getColor == "Orange" || getColor == "orange" || getColor == "ORANGE") {
        color = "#FF9900";
        el.style.borderColor = color;
    }
    else if (getColor == "Purple" || getColor == "purple" || getColor == "PURPLE") {
        color = "#6600CC";
        el.style.borderColor = color;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what the existing code does compared to what you want it to do. Also, take a look at this question to see if it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299666/how-to-dynamically-change-css-values-like-color-in-whole-app-etc

Comment: @SethDifley i just did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I corrected your snippet to make it work. You just need to access the style.borderColor of your HTML element.

  What I changed :
- #borders is for id="borders", so i changed for .borders and added the CSS class borders to your

  element

  The 'solid' value is meant for border-style property

  Your 'promptUser' variable doesn't exists so I changed it with static text

Hope this helps !

```js
 var getColor = prompt("Choose your color ", "Enter the  color ");
 var color;
 var el = document.getElementById("color");
 el.innerHTML = "Whatever paragraph message.";
 if (getColor =="Yellow" || getColor =="yellow" || getColor =="YELLOW"){
     color = "#FFFF66";
     el.style.borderColor = color;
 }
```

```css
 
.borders{
    background-color:#00ffff;
    border-color:#000000;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
 
<p id="color" class="borders"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help now i have another question , how can i put few others prompt input to the same window as my color

Comment: for example this prompt values to be in the same output window with borders and not seperate

Comment: Well prompt let the user only enter one input, so you could do a for loop on all your option names and use prompt to retrieve one value each time. But if you want all inputs in the same prompt window you will have to make a modal popup with an HTML form tag. Look here for modal popup : http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: I edit my question and code ,  if you could point out for me fixing places.

Comment: I'm still not sure, is using several prompt calls ok ?

Comment: Yes i guess, my question is on the final output i want border colors to change to whatever user requested , and rest values input to be in the same set border and not separate windows ..i hope i was able to explain my problem

Comment: Mmmh I think I get it. You want to change the border color to the user choice in all elements using the .borders class and not only one single element right ? If that is so, you would have to retrieve all the elements you want to change and do a loop to change them all. Maybe using document.getElementsByClassName('.borders') and iterate over all of them.